# Implementation of a data structure (Binary search tree) in c++

Tags: c++

I want to ask what's the best way to implement Binary search tree data structure in c++ given the following:

I already implemented BinaryNode class in c++, which have the following fields:

```
//|-------------------- Protected fields --------------------|
protected:
    U value;
    T key;
    BinaryNode* left;
    BinaryNode* right;
    BinaryNode* parent;
```

and supports the following methods:

```
BinaryNode(const T _key, const U& _value);
virtual void insert(const T element,const U& value);
virtual int height();        //Returns the height of the subtree where the activating node is the root 
virtual int nodeSize();      //Counting the nodes in the subtree where the activating node is the root
virtual int depth(const T& _key) //Returns the depth of the node with the argument key
virtual void printInOrder();
virtual void printPreOrder();
virtual void printPostOrder();
void printNode(int space); //Prints the subtree where the activating node is the root in a "graphical" way.
~BinaryNode();
```

And I implemented the BinaryTree class, which have only one field:

```
protected:
    BinaryNode<T,U>* root;
```

And supports all of the methods that the BinaryNode supports, with the simple implementation of just calling the right methode of the root. For example the implementation of `height()` would be

```
int height() const {
    return root->height();
}
```

Now, I want to implement BinarySearchNode and BinarySearchTree classes, but since every method of the BinaryTree except for `insert`would be the same for BinarySearchTree and BinaryTree, are relevant for the BinarySearchNode class, I would like to use this existing code. So I thought about inheritence, and since BinarySearchNode should have all of the methods of BinaryNode (and some more methods), I thought that correct design would be to implement BinarySearchNode as a derived class of BinaryNode, and BinarySearchTree as a derived class of BinaryTree.

But, during the implementation of the additional methods of BinarySearchNode I noticed that I have to downcast a lot. For example, here is the implementation of `insert` method:

```
virtual void insert(const T key, const U& data){
    if(key < this->key){
        if(!(this->left)){
          this->left = new BinarySearchNode(key, data);
          ((BinarySearchNode*) this->left)->parent = this;
        }
        else
            this->left->insert(key,data);
    }
    if(this->key < key){
        if(!(this->right)){
            this->right = new BinarySearchNode(key,data);
            ((BinarySearchNode*)this->right)->parent = this;
        }
        else
            this->right->insert(key,data);
    }
    if(this->key == key)
        throw "Error: Key already exists in the tree.";
```

Note that since I used inheritence, the pointer fields of the BinarySearchNode are of type BinaryNode, and so `this->right` is a BinaryNode and I cannot access its protected field `parent` unless I downcast it to a BinarySearchNode.

So I guess this design is not very smart.

How would you implement BinarySearchNode and BinarySearchTree instead?
Thanks in advance.

And I implemented the BinaryTree class, which have only one field:

```
protected:
    BinaryNode<T,U>* root;
```

And supports all of the methods that the BinaryNode supports, with the simple implementation of just calling the right methode of the root. For example the implementation of `height()` would be

```
int height() const {
    return root->height();
}
```

Now, I want to implement BinarySearchNode and BinarySearchTree classes, but since every method of the BinaryTree except for `insert`would be the same for BinarySearchTree and BinaryTree, are relevant for the BinarySearchNode class, I would like to use this existing code. So I thought about inheritence, and since BinarySearchNode should have all of the methods of BinaryNode (and some more methods), I thought that correct design would be to implement BinarySearchNode as a derived class of BinaryNode, and BinarySearchTree as a derived class of BinaryTree.

But, during the implementation of the additional methods of BinarySearchNode I noticed that I have to downcast a lot. For example, here is the implementation of `insert` method:

```
virtual void insert(const T key, const U& data){
    if(key < this->key){
        if(!(this->left)){
          this->left = new BinarySearchNode(key, data);
          ((BinarySearchNode*) this->left)->parent = this;
        }
        else
            this->left->insert(key,data);
    }
    if(this->key < key){
        if(!(this->right)){
            this->right = new BinarySearchNode(key,data);
            ((BinarySearchNode*)this->right)->parent = this;
        }
        else
            this->right->insert(key,data);
    }
    if(this->key == key)
        throw "Error: Key already exists in the tree.";
```

Note that since I used inheritence, the pointer fields of the BinarySearchNode are of type BinaryNode, and so `this->right` is a BinaryNode and I cannot access its protected field `parent` unless I downcast it to a BinarySearchNode.

So I guess this design is not very smart.

How would you implement BinarySearchNode and BinarySearchTree instead?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you move all the logic from the node to the tree, there is only one type of node.  Also, the only function that needs to be virtual is `insert`.

Comment: What's the difference between `Binary...` and `BinarySearch...`?

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk The nodes in a search tree are ordered by some ordering predicate.

Comment: @molbdnilo But then I'd have to let BinarySearchTree access to BinaryNode fields

Comment: @DirichletIsaPartyPooper Yes. Despite what someone might have made you believe, that's a good idea.

Comment: @molbdnilo So you say I should let BinarySearchTree be a friend of the class BinaryNode and then I dont even need the class BinarySearchNode?

Comment: It doesn't need to be a friend. Make the members public, but make the node type protected inside the tree. Like this `class Tree { protected: struct Node { ... }; };`.

Comment: @molbdnilo I think it would only be good solution for the BinaryTree and BinarySearchTree problem. What if I want to implement another tree with additional fields to its nodes? for example, an AVL tree. I would like the AVL tree to do everything the BinarySearch tree does, but I also want its nodes to hold the balance factor as a field

Comment: An entirely different option is to keep the node management in the nodes and make the tree templated on the node type; `template <typename Node> class Tree {...}; using BinaryTree = Tree<BinaryNode>; using BinarySearchTree = Tree<BinarySearchNode>: using AVLTree = Tree<AVLNode>;`

Answer (score 0):

Normal public inheritance of nodes is not a good idea. I strongly advise against using it.

An AVLNode has no job of being inside the regular BinaryTree. However, if you use inheritance, then [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) dictates that you should be able to use an AVLNode everywhere a BinaryNode may be used. This is not what you want.

You can use a variation of inheritance known as the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). Example code (not tested):

```
   template <class DerivedNode>
   class Node
   {
      private:
        DerivedNode* left;
        DerivedNode* right;
      // .. whatever
   };

   template <class DerivedNode>
   class ParentedNode : public Node<DerivedNode>
   {
      private:
        DerivedNode* parent;
      // ... whatever
   };

   class SearchNode : public ParentedNode<SearchNode>
   {
      // ...
   };

   class AVLNode : public ParentedNode<AVLNode>
   {
      // ...
   };

   AVLSearchNode a;
```

You can then templatize the tree itself:

```
   template <class Node> 
   class Tree 
   { 
      // ... 
   };

   class SearchTree : public Tree<SearchNode> 
   {
      // ...
   };

   class AVLTree : public Tree<AVLNode> 
   {
      // ...
   };
```

Things that others have said about placement of methods in the node class vs in the tree class still apply.